# Need to annotate a word without using "regexp"

Tags: regex, uima, ruta

Need to annotate/match a word (Chapter). The word Chapter occurs twice in the below Sample Input Text.

```
DECLARE Chapter;
   W{REGEXP("Chapter",true),-PARTOF(Chapter)-> MARK(Chapter)};
```

When I used Regexp condition,It annotates only the word which not contains Markup (i.e **chapter**) and the word which contains Markup is not annotated

```
(i.e C</span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman Bold; 000000; position:relative;top:1pt;mso-text-raise:-1pt">hapter).
```

Is there any other way to annotate?

**Sample Input Text:**

```
<p class="CN" data-name="CN"><span data-bkmark="para10000"></span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman; 000000">C</span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman Bold; 000000; position:relative;top:1pt;mso-text-raise:-1pt">hapter</span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman; 000000; position:relative;top:1pt;mso-text-raise:-1pt"> </span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman; 000000">O</span><span style="font-family:Times New Roman Bold; 000000; position:relative;top:1pt;mso-text-raise:-1pt">ne</span><span data-bkmark="para10000"></span></p>
<p class="Text" data-name="Text"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:12pt; 000000">This chapter provides an overview of nursing </span></p>
```

Comment: `without using "regexp"` but tagged as `regex`?

Comment: You need some sort of dictionary lookup where the markup is not visible. Try MARKFAST.